# JOIN 3 tables and COUNT for result

Tags: sql

I am using an a join query between three tables. My query doesn't display entirely my desired result. There are three tables `team`, `school` and `game`. For example, how can I display the total wins Lawrence North High School(`school_id = 11111`) has?

Current query:

```
SELECT school.school_name 
FROM school 
INNER JOIN team ON school.school_id = team.school_id 
INNER JOIN game ON team.team_id = game.game_id 
WHERE school.school_id = 11111
```

tables used:

```
SQL> Select * From Team;

   TEAM_ID   SPORT_ID  SCHOOL_ID TEAM_NAME
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1      11111 WildCats
         2          2      11111 WILDCATS
         3          3      11111 WildCats
         4          4      11111 WILDCATS
         5          5      11111 WildCats
         6          6      11111 WildCats
         7          7      11111 WildCats
         8          1     123134 Bears
         9          2     123134 Bears
        10          3     123134 BEARS
        11          4     123134 Bears
        12          5     123134 Bears
        13          6     123134 BEars

SQL> Select * From School;

 SCHOOL_ID SCHOOL_NAME                   SCHOOL_TYPE
---------- ----------------------------- ------------
     11546 Ivy Tech College              COLLegE
     11090 LAWRENCE Central Grade School GRADE SCHOOL
     11111 Lawrence NORTH High School    HIGH SCHooL
     19283 Howe High SCHOOL              High SchooL
    123134 Lawrence Central High School  HIGH SCHOOL
       192 Little Big Horn Grade School  GRADE SCHOOL


SQL> Select * From Game;

   TEAM_ID GAME_DATE R
---------- --------- -
         1 10-SEP-98 w
         1 12-SEP-98 W
         2 17-SEP-98 w
         2 18-SEP-98 W
         3 18-SEP-98 w
         3 11-SEP-98 W
         4 20-SEP-98 L
         4 21-SEP-98 l
         5 21-SEP-98 L
         5 19-SEP-98 l
         6 26-SEP-98 L
         6 27-SEP-98 W
         7 28-SEP-98 w
         7 29-SEP-98 W
         8 11-OCT-98 W
         8 12-OCT-98 w
         9 13-OCT-98 L
         9 14-OCT-98 L
        10 14-OCT-98 L
        11 15-OCT-98 L
        12 16-OCT-98 W
        13 17-OCT-98 W
        11 18-OCT-98 W
        12 19-OCT-98 W
        13 11-NOV-98
        11 12-NOV-98
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT count(*) as Total_wins FROM school INNER JOIN team ON school.school_id = team.school_id INNER JOIN game ON team.team_id = game.game_id WHERE school.school_id = 11111 and game.r = 'W'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `COUNT` With `Where` clause with `Group By` on the `schoolname`.

```
SELECT school.school_name, COUNT(game.R) as TotalWins
FROM school INNER JOIN team 
       ON school.school_id = team.school_id 
    INNER JOIN game 
       ON team.team_id = game.game_id 
WHERE 
   school.school_id = 11111 
   AND game.R = 'W'
```

If you are doing it for the one school you can just remove the `Group By` but if you want to get the count for all schools you need to apply the `Group By` and remove the `Chool_id` filter from `Where` clause.

Comment: You don't need `GROUP BY` if you're just doing it for one school.

Answer (score 0):

You will also have to specify the sport id in the where clause.

```
where school.school_id = 11111 and 
    team.sportid = (what ever the sport id you want to see)
```